# How to compare primary keys two tables, which is combination of five columns?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, and I want to update one table from another. Primary key defined for both is combination of five columns which I addded like below

```
alter table custompricingnew
add primary key (partNumberSKU(100), customerClass(100), customerName(100), svcType(100), svcDuration(100), durationPeriod(100))
```

How to write the where clause of the update statment ? Do I need to specify those five columns separately ?

```
UPDATE customPricingTest t1, customPricingTesttemp t2 
SET t1.customerId= t2.customerId, t1.customerNumber= t2.customerNumber, t1.custPartNumber=t2.custPartNumber
WHERE t1.primaryKey = t2.primaryKey
```

Nitesh

Comment: Yes. You need to join on all 5 columns individually.

Comment: And you have six columns in your primary key, not five.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a join with the `USING` syntax:

```
UPDATE customPricingTest t1 INNER JOIN customPricingTesttemp t2 
  USING (partNumberSKU, customerClass, customerName, svcType, svcDuration, durationPeriod)
SET t1.customerId     = t2.customerId, 
    t1.customerNumber = t2.customerNumber, 
    t1.custPartNumber = t2.custPartNumber;
```

This is a shortcut syntax that assumes that the columns exist with the same names in both tables, and your join should use equality comparison for all of them.

Also note the parentheses are required.

See also: [`JOIN` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You need to specify join on 5columns.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, these are 6 columns, not 5.

You have to join on the 6 columns either like this:

```
WHERE t1.partNumberSKU = t2.partNumberSKU
  AND t1.customerClass - t2.customerClass
  ...
```

or like this:

```
WHERE ( t1.partNumberSKU, t1.customerClass, ... )
    = ( t2.partNumberSKU, t2.customerClass, ... )
```